# Populating a hiddenfield with a delimeter. _delimiter not declared

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to populate a hidden field with the values that are added to my list box. I am getting the message _delimiter is not declared. So the hidden field value would be 123456,651456,654321 etc..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getSelected(source, eventArgs) {
      var s = $get("<%=NameTextBox.ClientID %>").value;

      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.text = s.substring(s.length - 10);
      opt.value = s.substring(s.length - 10);

      document.getElementById('<%= Listbox.ClientID %>').options.add(opt);
      $hidlistbox = $('#<%= hidListBox.ClientID %>');
      $textbox = $('#<%= NameTextBox.ClientID %>');
      $hidlistbox.val($hidlistbox.val() + $textbox.val() + '<%= _delimiter %>');
      $textbox.val('');
  }
```

```
  Private Sub PopulateListBox()
    Dim _delimiter As Char = ","c

    If NameTextBox.Text = "" Then

    Else
        ' Get value from text box
        Dim textBoxValue As String = Me.NameTextBox.Text

        ' Create new item to add to list box
        Dim newItem As New ListItem(textBoxValue)

        ' Add item to list box and set selected index
        Listbox.Items.Add(newItem)
        Listbox.SelectedIndex = Listbox.Items.Count - 1
        hidListBox.Value = _delimiter.ToString


    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript, you are trying to evaluate the server side `_delimiter` variable, which seems to be private to the `PopulateListBox` method.
You should either define a public `_delimiter` property in your code behind, or double check if you really need its evaluation in the javascript.

Comment: THanks I changed it to public and it is working but now I am getting the error Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object for the   $hidlistbox = $('#<%= hidListBox.ClientID %>'); line?

Comment: @user1342164 with the info I have available I'm not sure what could be that error. jQuery not loading correctly maybe(?), or since your evaluation is working, maybe it is breaking the syntax in some way?